# Using Spring 4.0 Security, JDBC with SQL Server no errors can't login

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am using MSSQL Server as DB. Using this query. I always get invalid user name and password. When I run the same query in the management studio something like this

```
select username,password, role from users where username=admin;
```

I get no results. If put 'admin' i get results back. I am using a very simple example as provided here http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/29799/simple-login-web-application-using-spring-mvc-spring-security-and-spring-jdbc

It throws no exception but every single time I get invalid user name and password. The only difference in my example and tutorial is I am using MS SQLServer  express edition

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, role FROM dbo.users WHERE username = ? "/>
                    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Here is the entire data source xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<!--  JDBC Connection -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the spring security xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username,password,role FROM dbo.users WHERE username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, role FROM dbo.users WHERE username = ? "/>
                    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you pls post your data-source-cfg.xml?

Comment: I tried doing both select * from users and even each field name, in both case a return is invalid user name and password. I don't get any exception s. It keeps displaying invalid login. It does make a database connection and the application startsup fine.

Comment: In your login page, are user and password inputs' value, name='username' and name='password'?

Comment: <ul>
   <li>Username <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value=""/></li>
   <li>Password <input id="password" name="password" type="text" value=""  /></li>
   </ul>

Comment: When I try in memory authentication it works with the right user name and password. So the user name and password is coming correctly from the ui.